# Efficient memory management with JIT?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, jit, memory-efficient

I'm writing a program that's doing JIT, and I'm currently setting up the executable memory like this:

```
void *mem = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
// write the JIT output to mem
mprotect(mem, len, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC);
```

I then clean it up like this:

```
munmap(mem, len);
```

This is rather inefficient, though, as I'm allocating an entire page (4KB) for everything I JIT, most of which only need a few bytes. (Note that my concern is more with the amount of page mappings, and possibly falling afoul of `vm.max_map_count`, than just the raw amount of RAM used.) For regular memory allocation, `malloc` takes care of this by wrapping `(s)brk` and `mmap` and keeping track of what parts of the page are used. I obviously can't just use `malloc` because it allocates non-executable memory. Is there a simple way to get similar behavior when allocating executable memory, or would I have to use a custom replacement for `malloc` to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use some *existing* JIT-ing library (e.g. [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), etc...). They usually handle these details. And you might use [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to render executable a page used by `malloc`